# Permission denied Iframe on same domain

Tags: javascript, iframe, dns

I have an Iframe inside an HTML page.
My website is on domain: abc.domain.local
My Iframe is on domain:  def.domain.local

Some of the test that I made not even return anything, and some of then returns Permission denied to access property 'document'

I've tried in 9 different ways (code bellow) and none of then works.
I've installed Cors Everywhere and disabled policy on Firefox (last version).

I've installed a lot of others extensions to disable cross domain policy on Chrome and Firefox and nothing worked out.
I've started chrome with some parameters to disable web security, and didn't work too

Unfortunately I can't set anything to webpage on def.domain.local, not event create JS files to use postmessage

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="button" value="1" onclick="teste1()" />
    &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="button" value="2" onclick="teste2()" />
    &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="button" value="3" onclick="teste3()" />
    &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="button" value="4" onclick="teste4()" />
    &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="button" value="5" onclick="teste5()" />
    &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="button" value="6" onclick="teste6()" />
    &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="button" value="7" onclick="teste7()" />
    &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="button" value="8" onclick="teste7()" />
    &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="button" value="9" onclick="teste7()" />
    &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="button" value="10" onclick="teste7()" />
    &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <br /><br />
    <iframe id="frame" name="frame" style="width: 1000px; height: 600px;" src="http://abc.domain.local">

    </iframe>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.domain = 'domain.local';

        function teste1(){
            console.log(document.getElementById('frame').contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML);
        }

        function teste2(){
            $.getJSON('http://def.domain.local/monitor.htm', function(data){
                console.log(data);
            });
        }

        function teste3(){
            console.log($("#frame").find("iframe").contents().find('body'));
            console.log($("#frame").find("iframe").contents().find('html'));

        }

        function teste4(){
            a = $("#frame").find("iframe").contents().find('body');
            console.log(a.innerHTML);
            console.log(a.html());
        }

        function teste5(){
            var iframeWindow1 = document.getElementById("frame").contentWindow;

            iframeWindow1.addEventListener("load", function() {
                var doc1 = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
                var target1 = doc.getElementById("html");

                console.log(target1.innerHTML);
            });
        }

        function teste6(){
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://def.domain.local/monitor.htm',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'html',
                success: function (data) {

                    console.log(data);

                },
                error: function (data) {
                    console.log("error: " + data);
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
        }

        function teste7(){
            $('iframe').contents().find('body').css('opacity','0.1');
        }

        function teste8(){
            var iframe = document.getElementById('frame');
            var iframeDocument = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
            var iframeContent;

            iframeContent = iframeDocument.getElementById('body');

            var iframeWindow = iframe.contentWindow;

            // you can even call jQuery or other frameworks if it is loaded inside the iframe
            console.log(iframeWindow.jQuery('body'));

            // or
            console.log(iframeWindow.$('body'));

            // or even use any other global variable
            console.log(window.outside_iframe_variable);

        }

        function teste9(){
            var req = create("get", "http://def.domainlocal");
            if (req){
                req.onload = function (){
                    console.log(req.reposnseText)
                };
                req.send();
            }
        }

        function create(method, url){
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            if ("withCredentials" in xhr){
                xhr.open(method, url, true);                    
            }
            else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined"){
                xhr = new XDomainRequest();
                xhr.open(method, url);
            }
            else {
                xhr = null
            }
            return xhr;
        }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Exactly what gives you this error? Are you trying to modify rthe iframe runtime?

Comment: when I execute "teste3" I receive this error. I'm trying to get the HTML from Iframe

Comment: Did you add `document.domain = 'domain.local';` in both abc. and def. ?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't set anything to webpage on def.domain.local, not event create JS files to use postmessage

Comment: if i'm not wrong you can't do it

Answer (score -1):

We finally achieve the result.
We could not do on FireFox, but on IE was pretty simple.
Just enable access cross domain through Custom Level Internet Options and get by ajax

Internet Explorer > Custom Level > Enable Access Data Source Cross Domain

https://www.webdavsystem.com/ajax/programming/cross_origin_requests

$.ajax({
    url: 'http://def.domain.local',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function (data) {
       console.log(data)
    },
    error: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});